# Activity title doesn't appear when app is running

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an activity with its own title in the toolbar. However, the title doesn't show up when the app is running.

This is the activity in Android Studio:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when the app is running on either a real phone or emulator:

[image]

The string for the title is stored in strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Glag</string>
<string name="selection">Seleccione el algoritmo:</string>
<string name="dda">DDA</string>
<string name="bresenham">Bresenham</string>
<string name="dataInput">Inserte los puntos a evaluar:</string>
<string name="x1">X1:</string>
<string name="y1">Y1:</string>
<string name="x2">X2:</string>
<string name="y2">Y2:</string>
<string name="button">Calcular</string>
<string name="hint1">0</string>
<string name="hint2">10</string>
<string name="title_activity_dda">DDA Algorithm</string>
<string name="title_activity_bresenham">Bresenham Algorithm</string>
<string name="x">X</string>
<string name="y">Y</string>
<string name="p">P</string>
```

This is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: share your style.xml with question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in onCreate() method of activity class:

```
Toolbar appToolbar;
appToolbar = findViewById(R.id.include_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(appToolbar);
setTitle("Activity Name");
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `Activity` add the following code in `onCreate()`

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // your toolbar id. this is needed to set your custom toolbar or externally added toolbar as the actionbar toolbar. or you have to use Theme as Dark or Light ActionBar Theme insted of NoActionBar Theme. 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); // sometime this may be set false causes no Title on ActionBar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And you can use **`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("You Title");`**   for setting  custom title on `Actionbar`

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want action bar, set it to noactionbar in style.xml and try this in your activity

```
Toolbar t = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(t);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");
```